# AdvancedCollectionView: sorting behavior is not correct

Tags: c#, winui-3, windows-community-toolkit, winui

Code example:

```cs
class Video
{
    public int id;
    public (int, uint, int, int, int, uint) SortValue { get; set; }
}

ObservableCollection<Video> _screenCollection = new();
AdvancedCollectionView AdvancedCollectionView = new AdvancedCollectionView(_screenCollection);
AdvancedCollectionView.SortDescriptions.Add(new SortDescription("SortValue", SortDirection.Ascending));

for(int i = 1; i < 25; i++)
    _screenCollection.Add(new Video { SortValue = (1, 5, 0, 0, 0, 0), id = i });

//Order is 3,5,7...
AdvancedCollectionView.RefreshSorting();
//Order is 3,4,6
AdvancedCollectionView.RefreshSorting();
//Order is 3,5,7
```

1. SortValue is same, so I expect the order is same with original collection -> 1,2,3,4,...
2. Why each time calling RefreshSorting(), the order is different.

So in UI, if one field of Video change, instead of just change that video's order, It changes a lot of other videos.

Comment: Can you post the code for the ``VideoComparer`?

Comment: Edited, I removed VideoComparer and use default comparer.

Comment: I saw your issue on the GitHub repo. For the moment, you can just use a proper comparer.